# I am receiving a TypeError: cannot read properties of null (reading 'push') for a clock in/out schedule

Tags: reactjs

I am a new dev taking over for another developer at work and I am also a solo dev as they were, I am using react as my code base and we had 6 weeks worth of turnover before they left and as time goes on, I realize how little knowledge was passed along to me. This is my first job but I am not looking for sympathy points, just the best way to ask questions and how to find the right questions I am looking for.

The code has not been touched for after I completed it, but now I keep getting this errors where it worked before. I dont currently know if its because my Twilio trial period has ended or if its another issue. I have troubleshot this code from my knowledge (which isnt much) but I am not sure where else to get answers from.

the code I am currently getting the error from

```
SendTextMessage(_type, _work_time, _notes, _week, _month) {
        debugger;
        let month = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May.", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."];

        let msgList = JSON.parse((this.props.lists).MsgTo);
        msgList.push(this.props.user.phoneNumber);
        let date = "";

        let mobileModeSend = msgList;

        let workTime = `Last Worked ${_work_time}.`;

        if(this.state.fridayTime !== null){
            date = FormatDateTime(new Date());
            if (_type === "Punching Out") {
            workTime = `Worked for ${_work_time}. \n` +
                `Total time worked this week: (${_week}). \n` +
                `Total time worked since ${month[(new Date()).getMonth()]} 1st (${_month}).`;
            }
        } else {
            date = FormatDateTime(new Date());
            if (_type === "Punching Out") {
            workTime = `Worked for ${_work_time}. \n` +
                `Total time worked this week: (${_week}). \n` +
                `Total time worked since ${month[(new Date()).getMonth()]} 1st (${_month}).`;
            }
        }

        `Total time worked this week: (${_week}). \n`
        let msg = `${this.props.user.fullName} \n` +
            `${_type} \n` +
            `${ date } \n` +
            `${workTime} \n\n` +
            `${_notes} \n`;
        for (let i = 0; i < mobileModeSend.length; i++) {
            const mobileModeMsg = {
                body: `Time Entry \n ${msg}`,
                to: mobileModeSend[i],
                from: `Auto Msg`,
                time: CurrentTime(),
                type: 'admin'
            };
            
            $.post('/api/send_message_async',{messages: mobileModeMsg},(response) => {})
        }
    }
```

I have ran the debugger to test all of the following that I am aware of how to do.

1. ran the debugger for the line it said it was having the issue.
   1-1. it returns null when I step over the line and when I console log the data
2. added an empty array with the msgList name to pull from to see if it needed that first, but that returned the same issue and I didnt need it when it was working from before.
3. I restarted the servers and FTP instances that have been connected to see if the upload had an issue, I reset the instance and launched it again. This cleared some other issues up but this one still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before the " let msgList = JSON.parse((this.props.lists).MsgTo);" line, if you console out this.props.lists what do you get?
Where is lists populated?

Comment: Thank you for giving me a troubleshooting start. I am still digging through the code base, I have not found out where the list if coming from but to answer the other part of your question, this.props.lists returns an empty array

```
ListName
: 
"Time Entry"
MsgTo
: 
null
MsgToList
: 
"[]"
```

Comment: @functioningObject in that case, msgList is null. you are doing null.push. You probably are expecting List.MsgTo to be an array? Or maybe you want to do: let msgList = JSON.parse((this.props.lists).MsgToList);
        msgList.push(this.props.user.phoneNumber);

Comment: I did find out that this.props.lists is getting the information from the database.
this.props.lists returns and array of objects and a null value for the MsgTo parse that currently exists, but also returns null inside of the lists array.

Should I be looking to make an empty array first, then push the array, then parse the database object?

Comment: I can close this now, the code was good but I wasnt told that our API permissions needed to be updated. That is what fixed the issue, I didn't have this information until later in the day when the previous dev told me.